# RequestQueue() in RequestQueue can not be appied

Tags: android, android-studio, request, android-volley

[This is my xml file][1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBb6o.png)I am created simple request from the server.But it shows some error as shown in given image.Please help me to remove this error.

[image: this is my MainActivity class file]

Comment: Because obviously RequestQueue constructor doesn't take such parameters ...

Comment: so what are parameter I choose to implement a simple request from my server.

Comment: What have you done so far ? Please provide the code.

Comment: Plese paste some code. @MansiSharma

Comment: compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    i'm using this dependency for android studio 2.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use StringRequest for single request to the server:

```
  public void onClick(View view){

      StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url
                , new Response.Listener<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {

          //Do your stuff on response

      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

          //Do your stuff on Error response

        });      
      VolleyHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue().add(stringRequest);
}
```

Here is your VolleyHelper class:

```
public class VolleyHelper {

    public static VolleyHelper mSingleton;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    private static Context mContext;

    private VolleyHelper(Context ctx) {
        mContext = ctx;
        mQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mQueue == null) {
            mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        }
        return mQueue;
    }

    public synchronized static VolleyHelper getInstance(Context ctx) {
        if (mSingleton == null) {
            mSingleton = new VolleyHelper(ctx);
        }
        return mSingleton;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. :)